# Outlook 2013 VBA Public Variable Doesn't Persist

Tags: vba, outlook

At the top of ThisOutlookSession I define:

```
Option Explicit
Public varTest As Long
```

I have a couple of test programs also in ThisOutlookSession.

Using debug I run this test3 program:

```
Sub test3()
  varTest = 42
End Sub
```

I then run test3b, but instead of varTest displaying a value of 42, its value shows as zero.

```
Sub test3b()
  MsgBox varTest
End Sub
```

Obviously I have some misconception about scope or persistence.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a Sub like this `Call test3 Call test3b` to execute them both in the same run?

Comment: Sub test()                             ' added this to ThisOutlookSession
      MsgBox CStr(varTest)       ' displays 0
      Call test3
      MsgBox CStr(varTest)       ' displays 42
      Call test3b
      MsgBox CStr(varTest)       ' displays 42
    End Sub

Comment: But I need to have some variable values persist throughout ThisOutlookSession as well as accessible from Module1.

Comment: So apparently, it is only lasting during a run... Maybe you will have to store these values elsewhere (text file, xml, ...), but I'm pretty disappointed too, it's not clean... I'll look into my outlook code and see if I had something like this to solve!

Comment: See my self answer below.  Essentially you just need to declare the Public variables and constants in a module and not in ThisOutlookSession.

Comment: R3uK, typical use is for the user to start Outlook and leave it running while they are logged in.  But, should the user close and re-open Outlook, you would be correct that the values would be lost, and if that is not what is desired the program would need to store values in files, or Windows global variables, or the Registry.  For my application this was not an issue as only persistence within a login session was required.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much more searching, I found the following by [Sue Mosher, Outlook MVP](http://www.outlookbanter.com/outlook-vba/49010-global-variables-session-variables.html):

> Remember that **ThisOutlookSession is a class module**.
>
> You need to **add at least one regular code module** to the project and **declare your global variables in it**, not in ThisOutlookSession, by using the **Public
> keyword** instead of plain old Dim

Sure enough when I move the Public variable definitions to a Module, the persistence issue is resolved.

Comment: OK Nice! I didn't know that! You can validate your own answer I think! ;)